# how to create a one to one chat page design without any pulgin in react native

Tags: react-native

please provide some information about creating one to one message screen design in react native

I[image] did this line for the design

```
<View>
        <View style={{borderWidth:0.0,width:"70%",height:Dimensions.get.height,marginLeft:10,borderRadius:5,backgroundColor:'white',marginTop:20,justifyContent:'space-between',flexDirection:'row'}}>
         <View>
         <Text style={{marginTop:10,marginBottom:10,marginLeft:10,fontSize:15,fontFamily:'Segoe UI',alignSelf:'flex-start'}}>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</Text>
         </View>
         </View>
         <View style={{borderWidth:0.0,width:"70%",height:Dimensions.get.height,marginLeft:10,borderRadius:5,backgroundColor:'white',marginTop:20,justifyContent:'space-around',flexDirection:'row-reverse'}}>
         <View>
         <Text style={{marginTop:10,marginBottom:10,marginLeft:10,fontSize:15,fontFamily:'Segoe UI',alignSelf:'flex-end'}}>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</Text>
         </View>
         </View>
         </View>
```

[image: this is image the message hi is the starting message it gose at top after that the automatically append after this message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a component with userId props and if userId similar to the currently logged-in user then render the component to the right side of the screen otherwise left side on the screen and add messages to the array to render it recursively in the flatlist component.

For Ex:

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

class ChatMessageItem extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const getDisplayTime = this.props.getDisplayTime;

        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                {this.props.user === this.props.senderId
                    ? <View style={styles.leftMessageContainer}>
                            <View
                                style={{
                                    ...styles.messageTile,
                                    backgroundColor: "pink",
                                }}>
                                <Text textStyle={{ color: "purple" }}>
                                    {this.props.message}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
                                <Text textStyle={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
                                    {getDisplayTime(this.props.messageTime)}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    : <View style={styles.rightMessageContainer}>
                            <View style={{ ...styles.messageTile, backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
                                {this.props.senderName &&
                                    <Text textStyle={{ fontSize: 12 }}>
                                        {this.props.senderName}
                                    </Text>}
                                <View style={{ paddingRight: 10, paddingBottom: 5 }}>
                                    <Text
                                        textStyle={{ fontSize: 18, color: "purple" }}>
                                        {this.props.message}
                                    </Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
                                <Text textStyle={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
                                    {getDisplayTime(this.props.messageTime)}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    leftMessageContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "flex-end",
        marginBottom: 3,
        marginTop: 5,
    },
    rightMessageContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "flex-start",
        marginVertical: 5
    },
    messageTile: {
        paddingVertical: 5,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        marginLeft: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        maxWidth: "80%",
    }
})

export default ChatMessageItem;
```

**ChatsScreen.js**

Add inverted={true} will help to start messages from the bottom.

Ex:

```
<FlatList
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    inverted={true}
    data={messages} // array of messages
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        return (
            <ChatMessageItem
                item={item}
                user={userData.userId}
                senderId={item.senderId}
                getDisplayTime={messageTime}
            />
        );
    }}
/>
```

Comment: thank you but I have a doubt about how to use this design with socket please tell me

Comment: and how to start message at the bottom

Comment: @Andruroshan Check out the answer, I have made some changes

Comment: how to push the value to the message through the textbox

Comment: Create a state of messages and push the new message in the state with the old messages

Comment: I tried but the message goes into up please tell me how to correct it

Comment: try to add a new message object at the starting of the array and mutate it with other message objects in the state

Comment: I add the message to the array but instead, it goes on top of the screen.

Comment: have you tried like setMessages(prevMessages => [newMessage, ...prevMessages]) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228557/discussion-between-andruroshan-and-jignesh-mayani).